# Entity Framework with optional parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using Entity Framework 5 is it possible to use a stored proc with optional parameters such that you do not have to add a null for each unused parameter?

The stored proc I have to use has 87 parameters only 2 of which are required. I really hate the idea of having to put 85 nulls in each call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739018.aspx) method (`DbContext` is a wrapper over `ObjectContext`) to execute some stored procedure and pass list of parameters:

```
FooEntities db = new FooEntities();
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
// create all parameters you need
var name = new ObjectParameter("Name", "Lazy");
var age = new ObjectParameter("Age", 29);

// call stored procedure with these two parameters only
var result = objectContext.ExecuteFunction<Result>("ProcedureName", name, age);
```

You can wrap this code into extension method for your `DbContext`:

```
public static Result ProcedureName(this FooEntities db, name, age)
{
    // code above
}
```

Usage will be like: `var result = db.ProcedureName("Lazy", 29);`

Comment: In case someone checks this question and is using EF6 o higher, you can do it using dbContext.Database.SqlQuery. If you have optional paramters you can set the value to DbNull.Value. You can create for building SqlParameters and when the value is null, it sets DbNull.Value. I hope it helps.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein thanks! Time goes by, everything changes) I'll add tag with appropriate EF version to question

Answer (score 2):

I am demonstrating @Francisco Goldenstein comment on the answer. 
The order in "EXEC SP_MySP @One, @Two, @Three, @Four" statement should match your stored procedure's parameter. 
The order of paraOne, paraTwo, etc doesn't matter.

```html
         public List<MySPEntity> GetMyData(int thirdValue, string firstValue)
        {
                var paraOne = new SqlParameter("@One", firstValue);
                var paraTwo = new SqlParameter("@Two", DBNull.Value);
                var paraThree = new SqlParameter("@Three", thirdValue);
                var paraFour = new SqlParameter("@Four", DBNull.Value);

                var result = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<MySPEntity>("EXEC SP_MySP @One, @Two, @Three, @Four"
                , paraTwo, paraOne, paraFour,paraThree).ToList();

                return result;
          
        }
```