# EF 6 omit optional parameters when calling a stored procedure using Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to call a stored procedure with only a subset of optional parameters, but it looks like I must include all parameters in order for Database.SqlQuery to function properly.  Is this the case, or is there a workaround to where I only need to pass the parameters I care about?

I am essentially trying to do the following, where the stored procedure has many input parameters, some of which are optional.  I want to be able to call the procedure and only pass the parameters I need to.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MySP] 
    @One INT, 
    @Two INT = NULL,
    @Three INT,
    @Four INT = NULL ...

var paramOne = new SqlParameter("@One", firstValue);
var paramThree = new SqlParameter("@Three", thirdValue);
var paramFour = new SqlParameter("@Four", fourthValue);

var result = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<MySPEntity>("EXEC SP_MySP @One,  @Three, @Four"
, paramOne, paramThree, paraFour).ToList();

return result;
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample code that explains what you have already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220593/entity-framework-with-optional-parameters)

Comment: I don't believe the link provided is valid for EF6.  I think it is EF5 and below.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I believe it is a bug. It defeats the purpose of having optional parameters if you must specify them, but if it is in fact a known requirement then there should be an exception thrown rather than successful return of 0 results as though the query was properly run.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and since no one answer I thought I would answer in case someone come across this.
To pass optional parameter you must specify the SQL parameter name in your query. Taking your code you need to do this

var result = DataContext.Database.SqlQuery("EXEC SP_MySP @One=@one,  @Three=@Three, @Four=@Four"
, paramOne, paramThree, paramFour).ToList();
That's how I get it to work in my code.