# Don't want to pass all parameters

Tags: c#

This is my stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[insertDetails] 
(
    @eno int, 
    @name varchar(max), 
    @address varchar(max)=null, 
    @phone varchar(max)=null, 
    @mailid varchar(max)=null 
)
as 
begin
    insert into para5 values(@eno, @name, @address, @phone, @mailid)
end
```

Below is my code:

```
private void Insert()
{
    TestEntities te = new TestEntities();
    var obj = te.insertDetails(1, "");
}
```

Here I don't want to pass all parameters.

Comment: what is `TestEntities.insertDetails`? how is it implemented? since the other parameters on the SP are optional, you indeed don't have to pass them all, but without seeing your `insertDetails` method, we can't see what you're doing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework with optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220593/entity-framework-with-optional-parameters)

Comment: TestEntities-> this is entity ,insertDetails->this is store procedure name

Comment: @ReddyP that... really doesn't answer that question. If you F12 ("go to definition") on `insertDetails`, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Your Stored Procedure is expecting at least two parameters (@eno and @name).

You should send them.

Instead, you can assign a default value for the parameter you don't want to send, example:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[insertDetails]
(
    @eno int,
    @name varchar(max) = 'NEW USER',
    @address varchar(max)=null,
    @phone varchar(max)=null,
    @mailid varchar(max)=null
)
as
begin
insert into para5 values(@eno, @name, @address, @phone, @mailid)
end
```